# execute a postgresql query from a file and write the output to another csv file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to execute a query from a file and write the output of it to a `CSV` file. I want to keep the delimiter as `;`. I have tried below queries.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -f \path\to\sqlQuery.sql -o \path\to\result\result.csv
```

This query puts the result into a file but it is in a postgres result tabular format.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -f copy(\path\to\sqlQuery.sql) to \path\to\result.csv csv header;
```

Above query is giving me a syntax error.

I'm looking for a way to use `COPY command` and `\f` or `-f` together so I'll be able to exceute the query from a file and also write the output to another `CSV` file with specified delimiter.

Comment: You might try `psql -t -A -F"," -f in_file.sql -o out_file.csv`. This doesn't give you value quoting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL script to use `COPY`:

```
COPY (/* your query */) TO STDOUT
   (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ';');
```